# Standard Deviation calculation in Tensorflow Math ops

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I am trying to convert following method (in python) in Tensorflow with c++ api.

```
def prewhiten(x):
    mean = np.mean(x)
    std = np.std(x)
    std_adj = np.maximum(std, 1.0/np.sqrt(x.size))
    y = np.multiply(np.subtract(x, mean), 1/std_adj)
    return y
```

My conversion is not yet completed. Can anybody help to calculate Standard Deviation with Math ops of Tensorflow c++ api?

```
Div(root.WithOpName(out_name), Sub(root, x , Mean(root, x, {}) ), {input_std});
```

I need to whiten a Tensor say a matrix with its mean & standard deviation ...

---

**Update 1:**

I have implemented a code but still the result is not same with python. Can anyone c++ Tensorflow api expert help? My current conversion is:

```
Mul(root.WithOpName(output_name),
         Sub(root, x,
             Mean(root, x, {1}) ),
              Reciprocal(root, Maximum(root, Sqrt(root, Sum(root,
               Square(root, Sub(root, x,
                Mean(root, x, {1}))), {1})), 1.0/2500.0)));
```

here 2500 is from my matrix `x` has elements 50x50 == 2500

Comment: Do you need it only in C++? I can show you how to do this in python

Comment: Yes, but if you please show it in python it might help me to convert in cpp